# Mpdf, how to make a book layout?

Tags: php, html, css, layout, mpdf

I've been trying to make a book layout using MPDF and i have seen in the official website to use the "columns" tag or "SetColumns".

But here is the problem:

When we use these functions, we will have a lot of blank space in the last document page, i want to use all the blank space in the left column, so only after that, i want to go to the right column.

How we can fix this?

(Sorry for the poor english) :(

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mPDF 7.x, initialise mPDF with the `KeepColumns` configuration option set to `true`:

```
<?php
// Require composer autoload
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
        'KeepColumns' => true, 
]);
```

This will ensure the entire first column is filled before moving to the next column.

[More info in the mPDF documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/columns.html).